# How can I serialize an entity in a sylius rest api?

Tags: symfony, sylius, sylius-resource

At the moment I have an entity that has a zone type field but when I serialize it it returns me as follows:

```
[..,
"zone": {
       "__initializer__": {},
       "__cloner__": {},
       "__isInitialized__": false
     },
..,
]
```

Comment: it's probably lazy loaded, as implied by `__isInitialized__` set to false. depending on your serializer, you may have to actively initialize the lazy-loaded entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because "zones" is a non-initialized Doctrine lazy collection, which means it has no data.
To populate it with data, you have to either explicitly fetch the associated objects from the database, add eager fetch to the association configuration, or lazy-load it by calling the getter before serialization.

For example, if you have a repository method with a query builder, you can add this code to fetch the zones:

```
        $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->addSelect('zone')
            ->join('o.zones', 'zone')
```